# C PF_PACKET Link-layer Processing

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, posix, posix-api

I'm trying to figure out the data structure that is stored in 'buffer' after the following:

`sock=socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHERTYPE_IP));`

`recvfrom(sock, buffer, 2048, 0, NULL, NULL);`

I'd like to be able to poke into the data structure and read in the link-layer, IP layer, and TCP layer if it is a TCP packet.  I tried the man pages, and some header files, but have it's just all over the place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're after is the [RFC that specifies how IP is encapsulated in Ethernet](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0894.txt). Sadly that RFC is *very* thin, but a [more recent RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1042.txt) includes significantly more detail.

Answer (score 3):

This is the raw bits that go over the wire (OSI layer 2). The [man page for packet](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/7/packet) explains it pretty well.

What I would do is to get the output of this and compare it to the output of a Wireshark session looking at the same data. You then should be able to correlate the two and see what's going on.

Comment: I did take a look at man 7 packet.  Based on the man page, it states: "The  link  level header information is available in a common format in a sockaddr_ll."  If you take a look at sockaddr_ll, you'll see that there is no way that structure can contain an entire IP packet.

Comment: The sockaddr_ll contains only the link level *header* information, not the whole packet.  The other data is in your recv buffer.  The format depends on the protocol you are sending.  Look at the RFCs for the appropriate protocol, e.g. IP, TCP, etc.

Comment: If you look at the top of the man page, at the #includes you will find header files that define the low-level packets (though not in structs, they use defines). The sockaddr_ll just defines an address.